# ASP.NET LinkButton - How to Hide javascript:_doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="cartLink" runat="server" Text="<b>Add to Cart</b>" 
    ToolTip="Add to cart" CommandName="Add" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
```

View Source:

```
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_productsList_cartLink_0" 
        title="Add to cart" 
        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$productsList$ctrl0$cartLink&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        <b>Add to Cart</b></a>
```

When hovering over a LinkButton I cannot lose the ugly `javascript:_doPostBack(...)` link status message that appears at the bottom of the browser.

Is it possible to suppress this?

**UPDATE 05-11-2011:**

I realize this is default behavior and most times I hardly notice it. However, it's only a problem in IE9 when the status bar is not showing (which is the default). Anyone know of a working hack to fix this?

Comment: what browser are you testing it in? I don't see any "javascript_do.. " as a tooltip. See this http://jsfiddle.net/upmne/   . It just appears in the browser status bar area but that is not intrusive at all.

Comment: Currently testing in Firefox 4.0 and IE9 on Windows. True, it's not very intrusive in Firefox. However in IE9, it appears in relief with a bottom shadow around it - really annoying...

Comment: @Bala, I have updated the question per David - I am actually referring to the status message that appears when hovering over a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the Javascript status message that displays in the bottom left of most browser windows, try setting the `onMouseOver` value.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="cartLink" onMouseOver="JavaScript:window.status='Yo, I'm the Javascript status text!'; return true" onMouseout="JavaScript:window.status=''; return true" runat="server" Text="<b>Add to Cart</b>" ToolTip="Add to cart" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("JOBProductIDName") %>' />
```

See [this page](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_status_bar_messages.cfm) for more info.

Comment: @Irish. Have you checked that you've got status bar messages enabled in Firefox?  Instructions in the link in my answer.

Comment: The settings are different in Firefox 4 than in the linked article. Also, I need to get this to work for default browser settings and at this stage I am more concerned about IE9 (has a shadow around it); see my comment to Bala above :)

Comment: I tried it with onMouseOver="window.status=...", still no luck?