# Asp.net LinkButton need to perform both link and function as well to show link in bottom of browser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, statusbar, linkbutton

My ASP.NET code is like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="LblSubid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LblSubName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SottocatENG")%>' CommandName="Category"><%#Eval("SottocatENG")%></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="LblSotta" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("SottocatENG")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="LblKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("KeywordDensityENG") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

It is working fine. When I click on that link button then it will call a function and store some value and redirect to another page.

**Problem** is when I hover a mouse on it, at bottom left of browser its showing

```
javascript:javascript:__doPostBack('rptMenu$ctl00$LblCatName','');
```

I want to show link instead of this like: `example.com..` So I was thinking to put anchor tag here like:

```
<a href="abc.com">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <a id="A1" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("SottocatENG")%>' commandname="Category">
        <%#Eval("SottocatENG")%>
    </a>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("SottocatENG")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("KeywordDensityENG") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</a>
```

But its not working. I have tried this: [ASP.NET LinkButton - How to Hide javascript_doPostBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944736/asp-net-linkbutton-how-to-hide-javascript-dopostback), but its not working in default setting.

Comment: where is the `click` event to fire

Comment: Did you try the Javascript code in the reference link that you have posted ?

Comment: yes  tried that.. but for that you need to edit setting of mozilla browser.. it will not work on everyone with default setting

Comment: click event bind with cs file and perform function....

Comment: pls add some answer if you know anyone something about this.. i m stuck on it